# how to move an element in an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, move

Hi I'm learning java an I was wondering how I could move an element in an array  from Position X to position Y. irrespective of where X and Y are in the array. Also i would like to close the hole in the array left by moving the element.
Thanks.

Comment: It might be better to use an `ArrayList` in that case, instead of an array. But what have you tried yourself thus far? Do you have some code to share, and what went wrong / gave you trouble with it?

Comment: What should happen with the element in the Y "position"? Disappear?

Answer (score 0):

This solution makes two assumptions: 1) that both X and Y are less than the length of the array, and 2) the "hole" is only the one value/slot that is moved.

```
int a[] = new int[];
int x;
int y;

// Populate a, x, and y

int b[] = new int[a.length - 1];
int j = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
  if (i == x)
    continue;
  else if (i == y)
    b[j] = a[x];
  j++;
}
```